# PHP regex 2 different pattern and 2 different replacement

Tags: php, regex

i'm quite newbie about regex i'm trying to replace 2 or more commas to one and deleting the last comma.

```
    $string1=  preg_replace('(,,+)', ',', $string1);
    $string1= preg_replace('/,([^,]*)$/', '', $string1);
```

my quesiton is: Is there any way to do this with a single line of regex?

Comment: Do you want to delete the last comma if it's the only comma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, of course that's possible:

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '/(?<=,)   # Assert that the previous character is a comma
    ,+         # then match one or more commas
    |          # or
    ,          # Match a comma
    (?=[^,]*$) # if nothing but non-commas follow till the end of the string
    /x', 
    '', $subject);
```

Comment: Doesn't this replace the last comma only if it's the last char in the string?

Comment: Thanks for answer and good explanation. Gonna accept soon(time limit).

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible since the replacements are different and the two commas may or may not be at the end of the string.

That said, `preg_replace()` accepts an array of patterns and replacements so you could do that like:

```
preg_replace(array('/,,+/', '/,$/'), array(',', ''), $string1);
```

Note that I modified the second pattern.
Hope that helps.